# Node js Registration App MongoError

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, authorization, registration

I am trying to deploy an authorization application to heroku. I cloned [this](https://github.com/braitsch/node-login) repository and created a Procfile with the following line: `web: node app.js`. I manage to upload the application by `git push heroku master` but when I open it it says "Application Error". The same is with `heroku local`. I get "Express server listening on port 5000" and then an error "[MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
However, when I follow the repository instructions

> In a separate shell start the MongoDB daemon.
>
> > mongod
>
> From within the node-login directory, start the server.
>
> > node app

everything is fine and the app runs. 
I would be so thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in looking at that code repo it is hard coded to connect to a mongo instance running on your local machine.  You can see that by opening the account-manager.js.  This is why you get that error when pushing to heroku as when the app launches there is no mongo instance running on localhost.

When deploying to heroku, if you want to run mongo you will have to setup a mongo instance with one of their mongo add ons.

Once you do that, you will need to edit this codebase to connect to the mongo instance you signed up for (through addon) vs localhost.  When you create an account with one of the providers you should be able to get a connection string and either use that directly in the code or use heroku's config vars.